# Enable mod_headers in Apache in Windows

Tags: apache, webserver, aem, dispatcher

I am trying to configure *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* in Apache to allow certain domains. Below is my *httpd* configuration

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

But the above config is not doing anything. Heard that we need to enable mod_headers to make it work. I run this *httpd -M* command and observed that header module is not present in my Apache. Can you anyone pls tell me how to enable?

Answer (score 21):

Here is my solution:

1. Open the file `httpd.conf` at `"your apache folder"/conf`
2. Find the following line using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in your text editor: `#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`
3. Remove the `#`
4. Save and restart your apache.

Comment: This worked for me in 2019! I'm using `Avada` theme on localhost. Is the mod_headers thing only an issue with WAMP?

Comment: Don't think so, @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 - there are ways to install Apache on Windows other than WAMP, mod_headers and other modules are a fairly common thing and if or if not they are activated by default / the installations' owners, is up to whoever setups / administrates the installation.

Comment: Very useful  note

Comment: On CentOS 8 there is nothing for #LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so and a search of modules shows "headers_mod" with no further reference.