# Axios post and problem with CORS in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: vue.js, axios, codeigniter-4

I trying post data to backend from Vue app and I have problem with CORS.
I using CodeIgniter 4 in backend.

This is my vue service:

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/admin/users/";

export default {

    create(userData) {
        return axios.post(apiUrl + "create", {
            firstName: userData.firstName,
            lastName: userData.lastName,
            email: userData.email,
            password: userData.password,
            role: userData.role
        }).then(response => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch(function() {
            const response = {
                status: 500,
                error: true,
                message: "Błąd połączenia z API.",
                data: []
            };

            return response;
        });
    }

}
```

Info from console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/admin/users/create'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I try add this code in *public/.htaccess* but it doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8081"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: could you solve your problem, I'm having the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. Try:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8081"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
</IfModule>
```

2. Enable apache module headers and restart the Apache service.

[Apache: difference between "Header always set" and "Header set"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502968/apache-difference-between-header-always-set-and-header-set/39551910)

[Enable mod_headers in Apache in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541069/enable-mod-headers-in-apache-in-windows)